# How to pass parameters in pagination in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I want to pass parameters in cakephp, how can I do that when I searched the sorted result and then click on 2 page of pagination it will not remember the url, I want to pass params which I selected form dromdown, how can I pass the params in pagination in my controller code is

```
        $membershipType = '';
    $status         = '';
    $timeSpan       = '';

    $fieldName = 'membership_Type';
    if(!empty($this->params->named["fieldName"])){
        $this->request->data['associations']["fieldName"] = $this->params->named["fieldName"];
    }
    $fieldName = 'statuses';
    if(!empty($this->params->named["fieldName"])){
        $this->request->data['associations']["fieldName"] = $this->params->named["fieldName"];
    }

    $fieldName = 'time_Span';
    if(!empty($this->params->named["fieldName"])){
        $this->request->data['associations']["fieldName"] = $this->params->named["fieldName"];
    }
```

I want to pass the value of fields name in pagination, how can I pass these?
in my view the code is

```
 echo $this->PaginatorManager->options();
```

I m really stucked here from two days, I dnt know wht can I do now? please help me, it will be appreciated many more, thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: You cannot tag it 1.3 and 2.x. Please chose the right CakePHP version here.

Comment: @mark well I am working the latest cake version, I tagged others also because there are many users in 1.3 and 2.x

Comment: That is invalid. If your code is for 2.x than tag it only with "cakephp" (parent) and "cakephp2.x). otherwise you are only confusing everybody and you will most likely get incorrect answers due to this. You are not getting any more attention this way, only more bad answers.

Comment: @mark okay I will be careful for next time. :)

Comment: Why `["$fieldName"]` if `[$fieldName]` would also work?

Comment: @mark sorry I forget to remove double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass 'url' option to pagination in your view like this:

```
$url = array_merge($this->request->pass, $this->request->named);
unset($url['page']);
$parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
if (count($parts) == 2) {
    $url['?'] = $parts[1];
}
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url' => $url,
));
```

More here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-PaginatorHelper.html
and here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper::options

If you widely use filters and additional url params - make an element which will handle it for you

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

I define the parameters in app.Config.routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/my_account/*', array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'my_account'), array(
'pass' => array('status')
));
```

Then in the view-file:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
'url' => $this->request->pass
));
```